# Composer Install VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008]

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I'm trying to do `composer install` in my laravel and suddenly this gave me something like first time to encounter

[image]

Tried to increase my `memory_limt` from 150M to `2000000000M`

But didnt works.

Or I just did it wrong?

Comment: Can you share more details? Additionally, setting such a high value makes no sense if it was not available on your machine - and I highly doubt your machine has 2 petabytes of RAM

Comment: I usually do composer install. these past few days but this is the only time I get that error so Im trying to edit php.ini

Comment: The error message that you get here is not related to your `memory_limit` setting in the `php.ini` file but to the amount of RAM that is physically available. How much RAM does your machine have and how does your `composer.json` file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same problem and you mentioned XAMPP:

Apparently old XAMPP installations (before ~10.2019) only supported 32 bits and with 32 bits there is a automatic memory cap at 2056M, that cannot be exceeded.

> Important warning for Windows XAMPP users or 32 bits PHP distributions
> Unfortunately, if you get this exception when running some script or composer when you are using XAMPP and the amount of max memory of 2056M isn't enough and you still see the exceptions, let me tell you that you are in a big problem as you will need either to optimize your script or if possible, to move on from a 32 bits distribution to a 64 bits distribution instead.

See more here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/816/how-to-solve-composer-install-update-error-virtualalloc-failed-0x00000008

Meanwhile XAMPP offers a 64 bits version - which solved my problem.

Maybe this helps you or others.